# Андроид приложение. По нажатию на кнопку она отьезжает и открывает скрытые кнопки

Tags: java, android, button, android-animation

[image: кнопка]

Стоит задача для экономии пространства на экране сделать кнопку по нажатии которой, она отъезжает и открывает скрытые кнопки, нажав на нее еще раз все сворачивается обратно. С какой стороны подойти к решению этой задачи?

Comment: задача не из простых. Готовые решения интересуют или свою реализацию будете писать?

Comment: Можно отрисовать, можно анимировать. Лучше и быстрей второе. Довольно простая анимация состоящая из 2-х частей, и с ней легко справится Animator, а если точней, то ObjectAnimator.